# cifar10 autoencoder with an error: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'x' with dtype float

Tags: python, tensorflow

I try to build privacy autoencoder with cifar10, and I refer to the tutorial for cnn by Magnus Erik Hvass Pedersen (https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/06_CIFAR-10.ipynb).
This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import time
from datetime import timedelta
import math
import os
import cifar10
from cifar10 import img_size, num_channels, num_classes

gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=0.03)
session = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))

cifar10.maybe_download_and_extract()
class_names = cifar10.load_class_names()

images_train, cls_train, labels_train = cifar10.load_training_data()
images_test, cls_test, labels_test = cifar10.load_test_data()
print("Size of:")
print("- Training-set:\t\t{}".format(len(images_train)))
print("- Test-set:\t\t{}".format(len(images_test)))
img_size_cropped = 24

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, img_size, img_size, num_channels], name='x')
y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, num_classes], name='y_true')
y_true_cls = tf.argmax(y_true, dimension=1)

def pre_process_image(image, training):
    # This function takes a single image as input,
    # and a boolean whether to build the training or testing graph.

    if training:
        # For training, add the following to the TensorFlow graph.

        # Randomly crop the input image.
        image = tf.random_crop(image, size=[img_size_cropped, img_size_cropped, num_channels])

        # Randomly flip the image horizontally.
        image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image)

        # Randomly adjust hue, contrast and saturation.
        image = tf.image.random_hue(image, max_delta=0.05)
        image = tf.image.random_contrast(image, lower=0.3, upper=1.0)
        image = tf.image.random_brightness(image, max_delta=0.2)
        image = tf.image.random_saturation(image, lower=0.0, upper=2.0)

        # Some of these functions may overflow and result in pixel
        # values beyond the [0, 1] range. It is unclear from the
        # documentation of TensorFlow 0.10.0rc0 whether this is
        # intended. A simple solution is to limit the range.

        # Limit the image pixels between [0, 1] in case of overflow.
        image = tf.minimum(image, 1.0)
        image = tf.maximum(image, 0.0)
    else:
        # For training, add the following to the TensorFlow graph.

        # Crop the input image around the centre so it is the same
        # size as images that are randomly cropped during training.
        image = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(image,
                                                       target_height=img_size_cropped,
                                                       target_width=img_size_cropped)
    return image

def pre_process(images, training):
    # Use TensorFlow to loop over all the input images and call
    # the function above which takes a single image as input.
    images = tf.map_fn(lambda image: pre_process_image(image, training), images)

    return images


#define the first privacy autoencoder parameters
n_input=img_size_cropped*img_size_cropped*num_channels    #24*24*3
n_hidden_1=math.floor(img_size_cropped*img_size_cropped*num_channels/2)
weights={
    'encoder_h1':tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_input,n_hidden_1], stddev=1/192.0)),
    'decoder_h1':tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden_1,n_input], stddev=1/192.0)),
}
biases={
    'encoder_b1':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1])),
    'decoder_b1':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input])),
}    
epsilon = 0.0005
train_batch_size = 128
batch_size = 128                         

def inference(images):
    xs=tf.reshape(images,[tf.shape(x)[0], img_size_cropped*img_size_cropped*num_channels])
    #encoder
    h=tf.add(tf.matmul(xs, weights['encoder_h1']), biases['encoder_b1'])   
    encoder_layer_1=tf.nn.sigmoid(h)

    #decoder
    x_tilde=tf.add(tf.matmul(encoder_layer_1,weights['decoder_h1']), biases['decoder_b1'])
    decoder_layer_1=tf.nn.sigmoid(x_tilde)

    #encoder_layer_1 for next dPA use, decoder_layer_1 for decoder_output, x_tilde for objective function( loss_restruction() )
    return encoder_layer_1, decoder_layer_1, x_tilde

def loss_restruction(images,decoder_layer_1, x_tilde):     
    xs=tf.reshape(images,[tf.shape(x)[0], img_size_cropped*img_size_cropped*num_channels])
    y_pred=decoder_layer_1
    f1=tf.multiply(xs,math.log(2))  #shape=(128, 1728)
    f2=tf.multiply((tf.ones_like(xs)-xs),math.log(2))  #shape=(128,1728)
    #difine polynomial coefficients to stuck laplacian noise
    coefficient_1=tf.add(f1,f2) 
    coefficient_2=tf.add(f1,f2)/1
    coefficient_3=tf.add(f1,f2)/(2*1)

    #compute global sensitivity to generate laplacian noise
    global_sensitivity=2.0*tf.reduce_max(
        tf.reduce_sum(tf.add(tf.add(tf.abs(coefficient_1), tf.abs(coefficient_2)),tf.abs(coefficient_3)),axis=1, keep_dims=True),reduction_indices=0)  #[1].*2   
    sen=session.run(global_sensitivity)
    lap_noise1=np.random.laplace(loc=0.0, scale=(sen[0]/epsilon), size=(tf.shape(x)[0], img_size_cropped*img_size_cropped*num_channels))
    lap_noise2=np.random.laplace(loc=0.0, scale=(sen[0]/epsilon), size=(tf.shape(x)[0], img_size_cropped*img_size_cropped*num_channels))
    lap_noise3=np.random.laplace(loc=0.0, scale=(sen[0]/epsilon), size=(tf.shape(x)[0], img_size_cropped*img_size_cropped*num_channels))

    #restruction function with laplacian noise as a loss function
    loss=tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(tf.add(
        tf.add(tf.add(coefficient_1,lap_noise1), tf.multiply(tf.add(coefficient_2,lap_noise2), x_tilde)),
        tf.multiply(tf.add(coefficient_3,lap_noise3), tf.square(x_tilde)) ),1))

    return y_pred, loss

'''
    Helper-function for creating Main Processing
    The following helper-function creates the main part of the privacy autoencoder. 
    '''      
def main_network(images, training):
    encoder_layer_1, decoder_layer_1, x_tilde=inference(images)

    if training:
        y_pred, loss=loss_restruction(images, decoder_layer_1, x_tilde)
    else:
        y_pred=decoder_layer_1
        loss=tf.constant([0])

    return y_pred, loss  


def create_network(training):
    with tf.variable_scope('network', reuse=not training):
        # Just rename the input placeholder variable for convenience.
        images = x

        # Create TensorFlow graph for pre-processing.
        images = pre_process(images=images, training=training)

        # Create TensorFlow graph for the main processing.
        y_pred, loss = main_network(images=images, training=training)
    return y_pred, loss


global_step = tf.Variable(initial_value=0, name='global_step', trainable=False)    
_, loss = create_network(training=True)
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(loss, global_step=global_step)
y_pred, _ = create_network(training=False)

saver = tf.train.Saver()
save_dir = 'checkpoints/'
if not os.path.exists(save_dir):
    os.makedirs(save_dir)
save_path = os.path.join(save_dir, 'cifar10_privacy_autoencoder')
try:
    print("Trying to restore last checkpoint ...")
    last_chk_path = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_dir=save_dir)
    saver.restore(session, save_path=last_chk_path)
    print("Restored checkpoint from:", last_chk_path)
except:
    print("Failed to restore checkpoint. Initializing variables instead.")
    session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())


'''
    Function for selecting a random batch of images from the training-set.
    '''
def random_batch():
    # Number of images in the training-set.
    num_images = len(images_train)

    # Create a random index.
    idx = np.random.choice(num_images,
                           size=train_batch_size,
                           replace=False)

    # Use the random index to select random images and labels.
    x_batch = images_train[idx, :, :, :]
    y_batch = labels_train[idx, :]

    return x_batch, y_batch


def optimize(num_iterations):
    # Start-time used for printing time-usage below.
    start_time = time.time()

    for i in range(num_iterations):

        x_batch, y_true_batch = random_batch()
        feed_dict_train = {x: x_batch,
                           y_true: y_true_batch}

        i_global, _, cost = session.run([global_step, optimizer, loss],
                                  feed_dict=feed_dict_train)

        # Print status to screen every 100 iterations (and last).
        if (i_global % 100 == 0) or (i == num_iterations - 1):
            # Print status.
            msg = "Global Step: {0:>6}, Training Batch Cost: {1:>6.1%}"
            print(msg.format(i_global, cost))

        # Save a checkpoint to disk every 1000 iterations (and last).
        if (i_global % 1000 == 0) or (i == num_iterations - 1):
            saver.save(session,
                       save_path=save_path,
                       global_step=global_step)

            print("Saved checkpoint.")

    # Ending time.
    end_time = time.time()

    # Difference between start and end-times.
    time_dif = end_time - start_time

    # Print the time-usage.
    print("Time usage: " + str(timedelta(seconds=int(round(time_dif)))))
    print("Optimization Finished!")

optimize(num_iterations=2000)
```

Unfortunately, I got an error message at the line when computing global sensitivity for loss function:

```
lap_noise1=np.random.laplace(loc=0.0, scale=(sen[0]/epsilon), size=(tf.shape(x)[0], img_size_cropped*img_size_cropped*num_channels))
```

The error message:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'x' with dtype float
```

The detailed error message are shown below:

```
Loading data: /tmp/cifar10_data\cifar-10-batches-py/data_batch_2
Loading data: /tmp/cifar10_data\cifar-10-batches-py/data_batch_3
Loading data: /tmp/cifar10_data\cifar-10-batches-py/data_batch_4
Loading data: /tmp/cifar10_data\cifar-10-batches-py/data_batch_5
Loading data: /tmp/cifar10_data\cifar-10-batches-py/test_batch
Size of:
- Training-set:     50000
- Test-set:     10000
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "BestSplits" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: BestSplits
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "CountExtremelyRandomStats" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: CountExtremelyRandomStats
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "FinishedNodes" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: FinishedNodes
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "GrowTree" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: GrowTree
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "ReinterpretStringToFloat" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: ReinterpretStringToFloat
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "SampleInputs" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: SampleInputs
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "ScatterAddNdim" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: ScatterAddNdim
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "TopNInsert" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: TopNInsert
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "TopNRemove" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: TopNRemove
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "TreePredictions" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: TreePredictions
E c:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\release-win\device\cpu\os\windows\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:943] OpKernel ('op: "UpdateFertileSlots" device_type: "CPU"') for unknown op: UpdateFertileSlots
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lee Janice\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1022, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Lee Janice\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1004, in _run_fn
    status, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\Lee Janice\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\contextlib.py", line 66, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\Lee Janice\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\errors_impl.py", line 466, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'x' with dtype float
     [[Node: x = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "autoencoder.py", line 158, in <module>
    _, loss = create_network(training=True)
  File "autoencoder.py", line 153, in create_network
    y_pred, loss = main_network(images=images, training=training)
  File "autoencoder.py", line 136, in main_network
    y_pred, loss=loss_restruction(images, decoder_layer_1, x_tilde)
  File "autoencoder.py", line 120, in loss_restruction
    sen=session.run(global_sensitivity)
  File "C:\Users\Lee Janice\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 767, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "C:\Users\Lee Janice\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 965, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\Lee Janice\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1015, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "C:\Users\Lee Janice\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 1035, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'x' with dtype float
     [[Node: x = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]

Caused by op 'x', defined at:
  File "autoencoder.py", line 25, in <module>
    x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, img_size, img_size, num_channels], name='x')
  File "C:\Users\Lee Janice\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\array_ops.py", line 1502, in placeholder
    name=name)
  File "C:\Users\Lee Janice\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_array_ops.py", line 2149, in _placeholder
    name=name)
  File "C:\Users\Lee Janice\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\op_def_library.py", line 763, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\Lee Janice\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 2327, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "C:\Users\Lee Janice\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 1226, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'x' with dtype float
     [[Node: x = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

I tried to add **session.run(tf.local_variables_initializer())** in loss_restruction() function, but it didn't work. I guess the error happened when lap_noise1 calling **sen[0]** and **tf.shape(x)[0]**. How can I fixed this part?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this line

```
sen=session.run(global_sensitivity)
```

Here you are requesting `global_sensitivity` which depends on your input placeholder `x`, thus you must feed a value to `x`, which is what the error message states.

I see a few problems with your code:

- You are first creating a session, then building your graph. I'm not sure if that's generally harmful, I've just never seen it done that way. Usually you first build the graph, then launch it in a session.
- While first creating the session, then building your graph would probably still work, your function `loss_restruction(images,decoder_layer_1, x_tilde)` definitely does not work as you intend, even if you would not get that error message. Here you are downloading an intermediary result to the CPU, do some computations with it and then use it again in the graph to compute the loss. However, the function `loss_restruction` is only called *once*, namely when you build up the graph. Thus that `sen = session.run(global_sensitivity)` statement is run only *once* as well. I.e. the value `sen` is actually fixed at training time and would not change during the optimization. Hence, I doubt that training your model would work, as back-propagation would not compute the gradients you might expect.

My suggestion is to rewrite your code so that you can omit the `sen = session.run(global_sensitivity)` statement. All you have to do for that is implement those three lines in Tensorflow:

```
lap_noise1=np.random.laplace(loc=0.0, scale=(sen[0]/epsilon), size=(tf.shape(x)[0], img_size_cropped*img_size_cropped*num_channels))
lap_noise2=np.random.laplace(loc=0.0, scale=(sen[0]/epsilon), size=(tf.shape(x)[0], img_size_cropped*img_size_cropped*num_channels))
lap_noise3=np.random.laplace(loc=0.0, scale=(sen[0]/epsilon), size=(tf.shape(x)[0], img_size_cropped*img_size_cropped*num_channels))
```

The Laplace distribution seems to be implemented in Tensorflow, check [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/distributions/python/ops/laplace.py).

Comment: thank you for your answer, when I try to use tensorflow function to generate the lap_noise, it solved the syntax error in my code, although it still have some problems with my logic error. :(

Comment: it print the loss is NaN%. I think maybe I write something wrong. I will recheck the code. Thank you! Another question I wonder is when there is no such a function I can find in tensorflow API, then how can I do with  this type of problem?

Comment: You will probably have to feed it from the outside, so have placeholders for `lap_noise1` etc.